# restart eht0 by ssh in centos7

Tags: centos, ssh, network-interface

I was able to connect to my Centos7 server by ssh in this way:

```
ssh root@xx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

I'm trying to install and configure Elasticsearch. In doing this I stopped eth0 by this command:

```
ifdown eth0
```

I'm trying to restart eth0 by ssh but I'm not succeeding...

Of course, by typing a command like this

```
ssh -vvv -p 22 root@xx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

I get a result like this:

```
ssh: connect to host xx.xxx.xx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out
```

and this is the result of connection by port 21:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xx.xxx.xx.xxx is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.xx.xxx [xx.xxx.xx.xxx] port 21.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I'm a newbie in linux terminal, any suggestions?

Comment: So, you shutdown the Ethernet port, and then cannot connect? And why would you try to ssh to port 21 (typically an FTP port)? I would expect the easiest way to get out of this situation would be to reboot the machine. If you have console access, you could probably do "ifup eth0", or reboot.

Comment: Agreed.  The only solution is a console login or reboot.  In the future, do not turn off networking if you intend to use the system over ssh.